# MySQL rank across multiple data sets for a scoreboard

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a scoreboard for a multi event competition.

I have a table with data like this:

```
id competitor  wod score
1  Noah Ohlsen 01  350
2  Noah Ohlsen 02  430
3  Noah Ohlsen 03  140
4  Noah Ohlsen 04  314
```

I have a SQL query that gets med rank per "wod":

```
SELECT 
    competitor, 

    FIND_IN_SET( score, (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM wodcomp.scoring WHERE wod='01' )
        ) AS wod01,

    FIND_IN_SET( score, (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM wodcomp.scoring WHERE wod='02' )
        ) AS wod02,

    FIND_IN_SET( score, (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM wodcomp.scoring WHERE wod='03' )
        ) AS wod03,

    FIND_IN_SET( score, (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
        ORDER BY score DESC ) 
        FROM wodcomp.scoring WHERE wod='04' )
        ) AS wod04
FROM 
    wodcomp.scoring competitor;
```

The result is:

```
Competitor  wod01 wod02 wod03 wod04
Noah Ohlsen 1     0     0     0
Noah Ohlsen 0     1     0     0
Noah Ohlsen 0     0     1     0
Noah Ohlsen 0     0     0     1
```

I would like it to be one combined row:

```
Competitor  wod01 wod02 wod03 wod04
Noah Ohlsen 1     1     1     1
```

Or even with a total across the events based on the combined rank in the different wod, like this:

```
Competitor  wod01 wod02 wod03 wod04 wodtotal
Noah Ohlsen 1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: This seems more like a display question, than a query question.  What method of rendering a display are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT competitor, 
       FIND_IN_SET( MAX(CASE WHEN wod='01' THEN score END), 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                     FROM scoring WHERE wod = '01' )) AS wod01,
       FIND_IN_SET( MAX(CASE WHEN wod='02' THEN score END), 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                     FROM scoring WHERE wod = '02' )) AS wod02,
       FIND_IN_SET( MAX(CASE WHEN wod='03' THEN score END), 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                     FROM scoring WHERE wod = '03' )) AS wod03,
       FIND_IN_SET( MAX(CASE WHEN wod='04' THEN score END), 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                     FROM scoring WHERE wod = '04' )) AS wod04,
       FIND_IN_SET( SUM(score), 
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total_score ORDER BY total_score DESC)
                     FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS total_score
                           FROM scoring
                           GROUP BY competitor) AS t)) AS wod                     
FROM scoring 
GROUP BY competitor
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b232/1)

Comment: Giorgos, really appreciate the help. I need to make it a bit more complex! what if I one of the wod would be time and the best score is the lowest how do I get the total? I can get the individual wod by changing sort order to ASC for that wod

Comment: how do i get  it so that a column wodX that displays the columnrank and then a column with the actual score?

Comment: ping @betsos can you have a look?